# submit large form data with post action return 400 error in .NET 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm using .NET 6 to post a form with large form data (about 200Mb), and there is no any file.

this's kind of my form in front-end:

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frm", @autocomplete = "off", @enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
...
}
```

and back-end:

```cs
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchList(VM_SearchList data)
```

quoto from [Skrface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55724168/10298544)
I have submited with an `VerificationToken` field in front-end, and decorated with a `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` filter in back-end, so it doesn't seems like a validation issus.

and from [Matthew Steven Monkan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45927665/10298544) and [this answer](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/612cf2d1-5b3d-40eb-a5ff-924005955a62.aspx),
I have tried all the setting there, like `DisableRequestSizeLimit` filter above, and also tried to decorate with `RequestFormLimits` and `RequestSizeLimit` filters which set to 500Mb.

```cs
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 524288000)]
[RequestSizeLimit(524288000)]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchList(VM_SearchList data)
```

And also tried to set in `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<HttpSysOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;

});

builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
{
    x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    x.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
});
```

or in KestrelServer:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
});
```

but it still can't work...

here is my request body information and error:

[image]
[image: error_picture]

I can post the form successfully with the form data that request content length is about 80Mb, but size like above (143,118) can't work, do I miss something else?

can anyone help? thanks a lot!

I've tried, the maximum form data size that I can post is about 130Mb (content-length: 133120)

Edited:
Here is my web.config on IIS server.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\BASE.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <!-- This will handle requests up to 500MB -->
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: bfaa51b3-9cb0-4908-8d5e-6289bd4f329a-->
```

Comment: In general, if the uploaded file exceeds the default size, It will report `413` in IIS,` 400` is an error in client, Configure `web.config` is not work in your project when host in `IIS Express`?

Comment: yeah, it's not working, I'll show my web.config in my question.

Comment: Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: No, I didn't find anything unusual in the configuration file you provided,I suggest you to check your client if there is something wrong in it.

Comment: I had the same issue. My form has dynamic fields so sometimes the post size is small, sometimes it's large. For a small post it was working, but large post was met with 400 error. 
The solution that worked for me was either:
1. setting the attribute [RequestFormLimits(ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue)] against the controller action, or
2. setting the value in the startup
services.Configure<FormOptions>(opt => opt.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue);

Comment: it works!!! thanks you so much, I will quote from you solution and mark as best answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1828662/steven-manuel) solves my problem. Thanks a lot!

It's quite a difference to change limitation of `form data` size (not `file size`).

You can use only [RequestFormLimitsAttribute.ValueCountLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.requestformlimitsattribute.valuecountlimit?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to decorate the controller, or set [FormOptions.ValueCountLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.formoptions.valuecountlimit?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in `Program.cs` in .NET 6 or `Startup.cs` in .NET 5 for your full site.

I have tried either way above, it will work!

Here's the sample code

- Controller:

```cs
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[RequestFormLimits(ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue)]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchList(VM_SearchList data)
```

- Program.cs (.NET 6):

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
{
    x.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```

- startup.cs (.NET 5):

```cs
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => 
{
　　options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue
});
```